# Suppose $T^2$ is diagonalizable and $\ker{T}=\{0\}$, and every eigenvalue of $T^2$ is nonnegative. Show that $T$ is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Suppose $T^2$ is diagonalizable and $\ker{T}=\{0\}$, and every eigenvalue of $T^2$ is nonnegative. Show that $T$ is diagonalizable.

Of course $T$ is an operator on $V$.
It seems to me that if I take a basis of eigenvectors of $T^2$ I can define:
$$S(e_j)=\sqrt{\lambda_j}e_j$$

So by definition $S$ is diagonalizable since every eigenvector of $T^2$ is an eigenvector of $S$ and so there's a basis of eigenvectors of $S$, and obviously $S^2=T^2$. I want to say that $T$ has to be of this form (perhaps $T(e_j)=\pm\sqrt{\lambda_j}e_j$), and therefore has to be diagonalizable. I feel that this explanation is flawed somehow, and obviously strange since I didn't use the given about $\ker{T}$.

Many thanks!

EdiT: Okay, I found a different proof(by someone else) that uses the minimal polynomial and @julien 's algebraic note. I'll give it a little more thought but I think I got this down. Thank you.

Comment: Consider $T=\pmatrix{0&1\cr0&0}$ to see what goes wrong when the kernel of $T$ is not trivial.

Comment: Ahh... then $S=0$ and therefore $S^2=0 \ne T^2$. Good point.

Comment: But how can I show it works well when the kernel is trivial? Also, is my reasoning flawed in any other way?

Comment: An eigenspace of $T^2$ is invariant under $T$, so it boils down to showing that $T^2=\lambda I$ with $\lambda>0$ implies $T$ is diagonalizable. But if $(T-\sqrt{\lambda}I)(T+\sqrt{\lambda}I)=0$, then...

Comment: Then $T^2=0$ in $\lambda$'s eigenspace, as in $\ker{T}=\{0\}$. I don't understand your point though..

Comment: Wait... Do you mean that $T^2$ is a scalar multiple of $I$ over all of $V$?

Comment: No, over an eigenspace of $T^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form). Since $\ker\ T = \{0\}$, it is nonsingular. Can nonsingular Jordan block vanish or otherwise become diagonalizable when computing $T^2$?

**Expansion of the idea:** Let $T = S J S^{-1}$ be a Jordan decomposition of $T$ (or, if seen as an operator, a matrix representation in a basis defined by $S$). Then

$$T^2 = T \cdot T = S J S^{-1} S J S^{-1} = S J^2 S^{-1}.$$

Now, $J = \mathop{\rm diag}(J_1, J_2, \dots, J_k)$ is a block-diagonal matrix, with $J_1,\dots,J_k$ being Jordan blocks. So,

$$J^2 = \mathop{\rm diag}(J_1^2, J_2^2, \dots, J_k^2).$$

Obviously, $T^2$ is diagonalizable if and only if $J^2$ is diagonalizable, which is possible if and only if $J_i^2$ are diagonalizable for all $i=1,\dots,k$.

Observe one such block:

$$J_i = \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_i & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
& \lambda_i & 1 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
& & \ddots & \ddots & & \vdots \\
& & & \lambda_i & 1 & 0 \\
& & & & \lambda_i & 1 \\
& & & & & \lambda_i \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Now, try to see what is $J_i^2$. You should get a nondiagonalizable matrix (with diagonals $\lambda_i^2$, $2\lambda_i$, $1$) whenever $J_i$ is of order greater than $1$.

Comment: I don't really follow... Sorry. I know Jordan form, but I guess not all that well..

Comment: I have edited my answer. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry to bother you with this again but I did manage to see (by hand) that a nonzero Jordan block of order greater than 1 squared will nondiagonalizable, but do you have an idea how I would go about proving that?

Thanks!

Comment: What would be the minimal polynomial of such a block? Here, it is crucial that $\lambda \ne 0$, as it affects the first superdiagonal in $J_i^2$.

Comment: Ohhh I see!!! $\lambda$ has multiplicity greater than one since removing the diagonal is not enough to make the zero matrix! Great, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

These things become very easy with the following fact, related to the notion of minimal polynomial.

**Fact:** a linear operator $S\in L(V)$ over a finite-dimensional $K$ vector space $V$ is diagonalizable if and only if there exists a polynomial $p\in K[X]$ such that $p(X)=\lambda (X-\mu_1)\cdots (X-\mu_s)$ with $\mu_j$ pairwise distinct in $K$ and $p(S)=0$ (i.e. there exists an annihilating polynomial which splits into pairwise distinct linear factors over $K$).

**Proof:** I believe this is done  in most textbooks. The only if is easy: take $p(X)=\prod (X-\mu_j)$ with $\mu_j$ the pairwise distinct eigenvalues of $S$. The if follows from the fact that if $p(X)=\prod p_j(X)$ with $p_j$ relatively prime, then $\ker p(S)=\bigoplus \ker p_j(S)$. $\Box$

**Application:** with your assumptions, denote $\mu_j$ the pairwise distinct (nonnegative) eigenvalues of $T^2$. Note that they are all positive, since $\ker T=\{0\}$. Now $T^2$ is annihilated by $p(X)=\prod_{j=1}^s(X-\mu_j)$. Which means that $T$ is annihilated by
$$
q(X)=\prod_{j=1}^s(X^2-\mu_j)=\prod_{j=1}^s(X-\sqrt{\mu_j})(X+\sqrt{\mu_j})
$$
which is a product of pairwise distinct linear factors. So $T$ is diagonalizable by the fact above.

**Note:** Your argument does not work because, if $T^2e_j=\mu_je_j$, $e_j$ need not be an eigenvector for $T$. Consider $T=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$ and the vector $(1,1)$ for instance. Finally, you see why there is a problem if some $\mu_j$ is $0$, that is $\ker T\neq \{0\}$. This yields a factor $X^2$ which does not split into pairwise distinct linear factors. So you can't guarantee that $T$ be diagonalizable. Sometimes it will, other times it won't (cf. Gerry's example).

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!